# Room @Ignore annotation generates compile time error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am using Room and here is my data class

```
@Entity(tableName = "buy_lead")
class BuyLead(
    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: String,

    @SerializedName("name")
    val name: String,

    @SerializedName("location")
    val location: String,

    @SerializedName("state")
    val state: String?,

    @SerializedName("message")
    val message: String,

    @SerializedName("product_service")
    val serviceType: String?,

    @SerializedName("posted_on")
    val postedOn: String,

    @SerializedName("formatted_date")
    val formattedDate: String,

    @SerializedName("seconds")
    val seconds: Int,

    @SerializedName("minutes")
    val minutes: Int,

    @SerializedName("hours")
    val hours: Int,

    @SerializedName("days")
    val days: Int,

    var bought: Boolean = false,
    @Ignore var error: String? = null
) {
    val postTime: String
    get() {
        if (seconds < 60) {
            if (seconds == 1)
                return "$seconds second ago"
            return "$seconds seconds ago"
        }

        if (minutes < 60) {
            if (minutes == 1)
                return "$minutes minute ago"
            return "$minutes minutes ago"
        }

        if (hours < 24) {
            if (hours == 1)
                return "$hours hour ago"
            return "$hours hours ago"
        }

        if (days < 5) {
            if (days == 1)
                return "$days day ago"
            return "$days days ago"
        }
        return formattedDate
    }

val address: String
    get() =
        if (state != null) "${location}, ${state}"
        else location
}
```

and it generates compile time error

> error: Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
>   public final class BuyLead {
>                ^

I have tried to move the fields inside the class but nothing is working. If I remove the `@Ignore` annotation from error it compiles then. I don't want to store error field in the database.

> Kotlin version is 1.2.71

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is:

- Decore the constructor of your data class with the annotation `@JvmOverloads`
- Add the field you want to ignore to the params in the constructor annotated with `@Ignore` and assign a default value to it

In this way, two constructors are created, only one of them contains the ignored field. Only the constructor without the ignored field will be used by room.

Here is a small example:

```
@Entity(tableName = "movie_entity")
data class MovieEntity @JvmOverloads constructor(

  @PrimaryKey
  val id: Int,

  val title: String,

  @SerializedName("poster_path")
  val posterPath: String,

  @SerializedName("genre_ids")
  @Ignore var genreIds: List<Int> = listOf()
)
```

Comment: This does not work in my case: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76857055/12204620

Answer (score 0):

Try adding primary/default constructor to your class.
Like this,

```
class BuyLead()( . . .
)
```

Another example,

```
class ByLead( . . .
    constructor() (
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a bug or feature, but Room expects to have either:

- parameterless constructor or
- constructor with all fields not marked with @Ignore

for example:

```
@Entity(tableName = "movies")
data class MovieKt(
    @PrimaryKey
    var id : Int,
    var title: String,
    @Ignore var overview: String)
```

will not work. This will:

```
@Entity(tableName = "movies")
data class MovieKt(
    @PrimaryKey
    var id : Int,
    var title: String)
```